# Why my smartTabLayout not show correct way

Tags: android, android-layout

i import the popular library smartTabLayout, and faceing a problem.

The gradle code is :

```
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
```

My activity just find id and setViewPager. but show error:

update, here is my code:

```
public class PictureActivity extends BaseActivity {

@BindView(R.id.viewpager_tab)
SmartTabLayout tab;
@BindView(R.id.viewpager)
ViewPager viewPager;

private FragmentPagerItemAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initTab(mock());
}

private void initTab(List<String> list) {
    initViewPager(list);
    tab.setViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void initViewPager(List<String> list) {
    FragmentPagerItems.Creator creator = new FragmentPagerItems.Creator(this);
    for (String type : list) {
       creator.add(FragmentPagerItem.of(type, HomePictureFragment.class));
    }
    mAdapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), creator.create());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

}

update, my xml:

```
    <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
         android:id="@+id/viewpager_tab"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         app:stl_defaultTabBackground="@color/white"
         app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="#3b9dff"
         app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="20dp"
         app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="16sp"
         app:stl_distributeEvenly="true" />
```

[image]

In fact, there are five tabs, i could scroll each fragment.

if i use no property, it show like :

[image]

When i use other library like [IndicatorTabStrip](https://github.com/AlexMofer/ProjectX/blob/master/indicatortabstrip/src/main/java/am/widget/indicatortabstrip/IndicatorTabStrip.java), it works:

Here is my xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <am.widget.indicatortabstrip.IndicatorTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/color_main_tabs"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:ttsIndicator="@drawable/home_picture_indicator"
        app:ttsTextScale="1.1" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code so we can see how you are implementing it.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @H.Brooks no, here i update my code

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I have mock 4 tabs, but only one show , i can scroll fragments, you can see the gray line has full screen, and have other vertical line , but the tab hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your xml:

```
<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"/>
```

You can also try setting the width by setting:

```
app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="10dp"
```

Comment: It does't work, here i update my code, and show error too.